# Ubuntu Server 15.10 doesn't recognize internet card

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface

I just installed ubuntu server (the installer connected to the internet with no troubles), and I cannot get it to connect wirelessly to the internet. I've googled to no avail, as there is no `ethX` device listed when I run `ifconfig`. Here is the output of `ifconfig`:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:84056 (84.0 KB)  TX bytes:84056 (84.0 KB)
```

I've tried running `wget --spider https://example.com` and using `sudo apt-get install <app-name>` and both have resulted in `Name not resolved`, even though the usb installer was able to connect to the internet perfectly fine.

**EDIT**: after running `lspci`, I can see the wireless network controller listed:

```
0c:00c0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I also saw the following listing under `lsusb`

```
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
```

**EDIT 2**: My ethernet controller is also listed under `lspci`:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

**EDIT 3**: I'm running the `4.2.0-16-generic` kernel.

Comment: wget or apt will not work with a loopback interface. Try `lsusb` - do you see your NIC now? (You have a usb to rj45 network adapter right?)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `lspci` and/or `lsusb`, showing the WiFI device entry. (If you are completely sure you know which lines are relevant you may omit the other lines from your question.)

Comment: This should be supported by the `e1000e` driver / kernel module, which you can verify with a quick google. Check and see if you have that module loaded. Intel drivers are usually problem-free. See for example https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817/Network-Adapter-Driver-for-PCI-E-Gigabit-Network-Connections-under-Linux- What kernel are you running? It looks like this card has been supported by this driver for a long time.

Comment: After running `make install` in the `src` directory of the install, it doesn't appear in the tab completion of `modprobe`, even though I've followed the directions perfectly and gotten no errors or warnings. I get `e100`, and `e1000`, but not `e1000e`. And loading the `e100` and `e1000` modules didn't help. And `ifconfig` never changes. Rebooting still didn't allow me to load the kernel module.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to get the `Ultimate N Wifi Link` to work, not necessarily the ethernet controller. Does the wireless controller depend on the ethernet? because I don't necessarily need the drivers for it if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with upgrades from the installation itself. Some Driver files or the files required for compiling the driver might be missing.